# How to attract maps when it zooms

Tags: google-maps, maps

In my application Iam facing a issue with Maps..

The initial mapview comes up zoomed into my location but then after a few seconds, it flashes and then gives me a view of the West Coast of the US.  Please tell me some points so that it remains at the zoomed in view so that the user can see their current location without having to zoom in.

Comment: Presumably the map is being told to do that. A link to demonstrate the problem would help diagnose the cause.

Comment: Seems you copied an example from somewhere and changed some parameters without understanding what it actually does.

Comment: @Andrew Leach :::\This is fully confidiential i cannot provide you any links for this

Comment: @ Andrew Leach :: thank you so much..i solved the issue